# Invalid ID for ZoneOffset

Tags: mysql, date, java-8, timestamp, datetimeoffset

I am trying to convert from `java.sql.timestamp` to `OffsetDateTime` so that i can return `ISO8601` standard string in my rest api. I am using this code to convert from `timestamp` to `OffsetDateTime`

```
public static OffsetDateTime sqlTimetampeToOffsetDateTime(Timestamp ts, String timeZone)
{
    if (ts == null)
    {
        return null;
    }

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(ts);
    ZoneOffset offset = ZoneOffset.of(timeZone);
    return OffsetDateTime.of(
            cal.get(Calendar.YEAR),
            cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1,
            cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH),
            cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY),
            cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE),
            cal.get(Calendar.SECOND),
            cal.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND)*1000000,
            offset);
}
```

However, the code fails at `ZoneOffset offset = ZoneOffset.of(timezone)` for value `Europe/Copenhagen`.

I used following code to print list of all timezones and i do see `Europe/Copenhagen` in that list

```
    Set<String> allZones = ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds();
    LocalDateTime dt = LocalDateTime.now();

    List<String> zoneList = new ArrayList<String>(allZones);
    Collections.sort(zoneList);

    for (String s : zoneList) {
        ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of(s);
        ZonedDateTime zdt = dt.atZone(zone);
        ZoneOffset offset = zdt.getOffset();
        int secondsOfHour = offset.getTotalSeconds() % (60 * 60);
        String out = String.format("%35s %10s%n", zone, offset);
        System.out.printf(out);
    }
```

Now I don't understand what is going on. How can i convert `java.sql.timestamp` to `ISO8601` string (i don't care if i have to use `OffsetDateTime` or not. I would prefer not to use any third party library

http://pastebin.com/eHJKWpAv

Comment: What is your datatype in your database? timestamp with timezone? Something else?

Comment: In database i have timestam e.g., `2016-05-23 15:00:00.0` and i have another column which has timezone e.g., `Europe/Copenhagen`. Thats why i am passing `timezone` as a separate string.

Comment: The expression `ZoneOffset.of("Europe/Copenhagen")` must fail because that zone id is NOT just an offset (contains additional informations like daylight saving rules). In this case you have first to construct a `ZonedDateTime` and then derive from this an `OffsetDateTime` or an `Instant`.

Answer (score 10):

ZoneOffset only makes sense when dealing with a specific point in time.  In Europe/London we currently use either BST or GMT depending on the time of year.  However, 100 years ago (give or take), Europe/London didn't have BST.  ZoneOffset.of() only retrieves zone offsets from an internal cache which is only populated when ZoneOffset.ofTotalSeconds() is called.  This is poorly documented.  However, an easy solution exists:

```
ZoneId.of("Europe/London").getRules().getOffset(Instant.now());
```

which returns the correct ZoneOffset for Europe/London for right now (e.g. today)

Answer (score 2):

If you have the ZoneId, it's pretty trivial to use the Instant class to do this:

```
Timestamp t = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());

ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of("Europe/Copenhagen");

OffsetDateTime offsetDateTime = ZonedDateTime
    .ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochMilli(t.getTime()), zone)
    .toOffsetDateTime();
```

Comment: How do you know what zoneIds you have available? Any Constants, without querying them beforehand manually?

Answer (score -1):

I did manage to convert it but i am not sure if it is the right way to do so or not. Here is my code for someone else who is looking for the answer

```
public static OffsetDateTime sqlTimetampeToOffsetDateTime(Timestamp ts, String timeZone)
{
    if (ts == null)
    {
        return null;
    }

    ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of(timeZone);

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(ts);
    ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.of(
            cal.get(Calendar.YEAR),
            cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1,
            cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH),
            cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY),
            cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE),
            cal.get(Calendar.SECOND),
            cal.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND) * 1000000,
            zoneId);
    return zdt.toOffsetDateTime();
}
```

Where `timeZone` is in the form of `Europe/Copenhagen` ... you can see the full list that is supported by `Java8` in my pastebin url posted in the question

Comment: I think `return ts.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.of(timeZone)).toOffsetDateTime();` is all that is needed.

Comment: your code is adding offset to the resulting time. Just wanted to write it here so that if someone else is reading he knows the difference.

Comment: Okay, then it is `ts.toLocalDateTime().atZone(ZoneId.of(timeZone)).toOffsetDateTime();`.